# Create an array of strings with a combination of text found in a file using python

Tags: python, arrays, string

I am fairly new to python scripting and am looking for a solution for the following task:

1. Open text-file
2. Create an array of strings which consists out of text (name + property) that have to be found inside the text file (multiple lines)

Excerpt of the file can be found below:

```
**HM_comp_by_property "4512_solid"    34
*SOLID SECTION, ELSET=flange2, MATERIAL=WN1.4512
**HM_comp_by_property "4512_2_0mm"     7
*SHELL SECTION, ELSET=ccc_pin , TEMPERATURE =        3, MATERIAL=WN1.4512
2.0       ,         3
```

What has to be created in the end is an array consisting of the different combinations of 'elset'-names and their material:

```
flange2    WN1.4512
ccc_pin    WN1.4512
```

Hopefully you can provide me with some tips to get me started. I don't expect a complete solution, some guidelines would be nice :-).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Assuming the format is pretty consistent, this seems like a case for a fairly straightforward capturing RegEx (assuming you've used regular expressions in other languages, perhaps?) among other string operations that folks will suggest.

Comment: Are there likely to be more than a single value per ELSET name? I wonder if what you actually meant you need is a Python Dictionary (http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)? But that would require on one "key" per value. Maybe I'm overthinking your use of the word "array"?

Comment: Is this a dict/class in your code? If so, use `pickle` to load/save the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Untested.</strike> Works on supplied example. I assumed that what you really want is a dictionary with the ELSET as the key.

```
import re

def _search_line_for_key_value (key, line):
    key_finder = re.finditer(key + r'\s*=', line)
    try:
        first_match = next(key_finder)
    except StopIteration:
        return None
    value = re.match(r'\s*([^,\s]+)', line[first_match.end():])
    if not value:
        raise ValueError('A line was encountered with an invalid %s value' % key)
    try:
        next(key_finder)
    except StopIteration:
        return value.group(1)
    else:
        raise ValueError('A line was encountered with more than one %s value' % key)

def get_elset_material_dict (filename):
    results = {}
    for line in open(filename):
        elset = _search_line_for_key_value('ELSET', line)
        if elset is not None:
            results[elset] = _search_line_for_key_value('MATERIAL', line)
    return results
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked like a charm! Only thing I changed is the way it handles the case where no material is found. That entry will be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a one-liner, here's one way to do it:

```
with open('input_file.txt') as f:
   array = [x for x in [re.findall(r'(?:ELSET|MATERIAL)=([^\s,]*)', line) for line in f] if x]
```

In essence,

- Open the file
- Read the lines, one at a time: `for line in f`
- Find the data you need:
      `re.findall(r'(?:ELSET|MATERIAL)=([^\s,]*)', line)`
- Get rid of blank entries:
      `[x for x in [...] if x]`

You might be interested in the `re.findall()` step:

- `re.findall` returns an array of all matches
- The first arg is the pattern:

  - `r''` -- use a raw string, no `\\` tomfoolery.
  - `(?:ELSET|MATERIAL)` - match those keywords, but don't remember them
  - `([^\s,]*)` - match a sequence of non-whitespace, non-comma characters, and remember them
  - `(?:ELSET|MATERIAL)=([^\s,]*)` - match text like `ELSET=foo.bar` and remember `foo.bar`

So, the whole thing searches for the two patterns we care about, line-by-line, and returns an array of the values of those `TYPE=VAL` pairs.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Is it possible to only use the line-data when both keywords are found in the same? It can occur that in other lines the keywords only appear separately.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re   

fp = open("input.txt")

ans = {}     // Dictionary to store the values
for line in fp:
    if re.match("\*[^\*]", line):    // If the line starts with only one *
        elset = re.findall(".*ELSET=([^\s,]*)", line)[0]
        material = re.findall(".*MATERIAL=([^\s,]*)", line)[0]

        ans[elset] = material

print ans
```